# HTTP_USER_AGENT - differentiating ipad vs ipad pro

Tags: php, ios, device, detection

When I do `var_dump(HTTP_USER_AGENT)` on my google screen selecting the devices **IPAD** and **IPAD PRO** I get this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A5341f Safari/604.1

Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A5341f Safari/604.1
```

Theres no difference between these two while the resolution is different for each. I need to load a file depending on if its ipad or its ipad pro.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If there is no distinction between the two then you cannot differ between them. But such approach is questionable anyway, since those header entries can be altered. The robust approach is to detect the resolution and react on that instead of trying to guess the device type. You can react on the resolution either in your css rule set (see under "responsive" design for examples) or, if that is not enough, you can use some javascript code for that.

Comment: In what way do you need to "load a file"? Using PHP? What type of file?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to set different stylesheet rule for differentiating device sizes

---

```
<html>
<head>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (max-device-width: 1668px) and (device-height: 2388px) and (orientation:portrait)" href="ipad-pro-portrait.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (max-device-width: 1668px) and (device-height: 2388px) and (orientation:landscape)" href="ipad-pro-landscape.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait)" href="ipad-portrait.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)" href="ipad-landscape.css" />

</head>
```